# Laravel как передать данные в форму регистрации

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Есть стандартная форма регистрации register.blade.php

Мне нужно передать в неё массивы из 3-х разных таблиц.

К примеру сделать выборку из базы positions и записать в массив $positions чтоб потом вывести все должности при регистрации и т д

Как правильно в этом случае организовать это ?

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере, который отвечает за этот view

```
public function "имя метода"() {
// совершаете выборки
$positions = App\Positions::all();
$users = App\User::where('name','Алексей Назаров')->first();
$somethingElse = App\Something::all();
//передаете в шаблон
return view('register',compact('users','positions', 'somethingElse'));


}
```

в шаблоне будут доступны users,positions + somethingElse.